# angular/firebase remove ng-repeat item and re-add

Tags: angularjs, mapbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have mapbox marker objects that are being stored in a Firebase array. They are being loaded as geojson markers on my map and I am also listing those objects in a container with a simple ng-repeat. My goal is to have a function where, if the particular marker is out of view, to remove that marker from the DOM. If the marker comes back into view, to include that back into the ng-repeated list.

Let's say my list is being displayed like this:

```
<div id="list-item-container">
    <div class="list-item" title="{{marker.name}}" ng-repeat="marker in markers">{{marker.name}}</div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I'm trying to hide and show these list items based on them being in the map bounds like so:

```
       var markers = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
            .addTo(map);

       markers.setGeoJSON($scope.driverMarkers);

       var listingsFromMarker = function() {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();

            markers.eachLayer(function(marker) {

                var inBounds = [], id = marker.toGeoJSON().$id;
                var idElement = $('.list-item[title="'+marker.toGeoJSON().$id+'"]');

                if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
                    HOW DO I GET THIS ITEM BACK IN MY LIST???
                } else {
                    idElement.remove();
                }
            });
        };

       map.on('move', function() {
            listingsFromMarker();
       });
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction on how to place this ng-repeated item back into the DOM?

Thank you.

Comment: Posted my question a few days ago and still haven't heard from anyone. Hoping to get some help. Thank you if you can offer your time!

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not the Angular way to do things. Deleting the DOM element that was created by `ng-repeat` binding ruins the concept... why would you use Angular at all in this case.. In all cases DOM should be manipulated with the help of Angular directives which are controlled via model.
2. Thus you should store two arrays. One is the real data - all markers. Another contains only markers that are desired to be shown at this moment in the list.

It will look something like below

In view

```
<div class="list-item" 
     ng-repeat="marker in markersInView"
     title="{{marker.name}}">{{marker.name}}</div>
```

In controller

```
  var listingsFromMarker = function() {
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var inBounds = [];
        markers.eachLayer(function(marker) {
            if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
                inBounds.push(marker);
            } 
        });
        $scope.markersInView = inBounds;
        $scope.$apply();//as this happens on mapbox event it isn't in $digest cycle
        //so need to tell Angular to update bindings
    };
```

And of cause you need to initialize `$scope.markersInView` somewhere in the beginning. This code is not presented in OP so I don't invent it. I guess you will figure out how to filter markers on first show

Comment: Thank you Kirill. I will test this out and hopefully accept your answer when I'm ready to. Really appreciate it.